# SQLplus: how to modify a value in a trigger, using before update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

i want to update this value using a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
BEFORE UPDATE OF value
ON table FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN NEW.value < 0
BEGIN
  IF :new.value < 0 then
    :new.value := 0 ;
  end if;
END
```

when i see my table nothing has been changed to 0 if i put in a new value < 0

thanks.

Comment: Which database system do you use? SQL Plus is a shell for Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON table 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF :new.value < 0 
  then
    :new.value := 0 ;
  end if;
END
```

OR

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NumberOfBooks
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON book
    FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.value < 0)
BEGIN 
    :new.salary := 0;
END;
```

Comment: still the same :( it doesn't change, if i add an error msg it shows the msg but still the value doesnt go to 0 if i put a negative number

Comment: @KingAzaiez please accept and click on upward arrow as well. Thanks a lot